# .NET Framework 4.7.2, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, .net

I having a problem when running our .NET project in debug mode
The Target Framework .NET Framework 4.7.2 and we our using Visual studio 2012

This error occurs when running the debug and will cause the debugging process to stop. [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2y4c.png) and [Call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUpjK.png)

[image]

I try to use the Microsoft Symbols Server
Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> Select Microsoft Symbols Server and only specified module

and Disable the Just my Code
Options -> Debugging -> General -> Un-Select Just my Code and Select Enable .Net Framework source stepping

but only same error but different call stack
[Here is the call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RpFb.png)

Even so we can debug the app but the need of re run the debug is take time. I don't know what the problem is or if I am missing something.

Comment: Post the code and full exception text as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied, tested, googled or compiled. Why are you using such an old, discontinued Visual Studio version though? That supported .NET Framework 4.5, not 4.7.2. The image you posted shows a problem with a VS component, probably a bug that was fixed in the last 11 years. Or it may be caused because the VS feature just doesn't work well with 4.7.2.

Comment: There's really no point trying to find why an 11 year old IDE doesn't work with a framework and runtime released 6 years later. Install the latest Visual Studio Community Edition and try your code there. I suspect you won't encounter this problem

Comment: Visual Studio replaced the Web Development Server with IIS Express [as far back as VS 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120)) and .NET Framework 4.5.1. VS 2012 just wasn't built to work with any newer .NET Framework versions, certainly not any of the current versions

Comment: BTW even if you or your company bought VS 2012, it's [already reached End Of Life](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2012). There really is no reason to keep using it

Answer (score 0):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This occurs when the instance of that object is null.
For example I have a class named student and I want to use this object.
My code is:

```
public student st ;
public void Do(){
st.create();
}
```

At `st.create` an error will be thrown because **I did not fill** the st object.
The correct way can be:

```
    public student st ;
    public void Do(){
st = new student();
    st.create();
    }
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> can occure in some other things but the main reason is that the object is null